# Child browser doesn't close when the Android back button is pressed

Tags: android, back-button, trigger.io

If I correctly remember, the child browser (**forge.tabs** module) was always closed by pressing the back button on Android. However, it seems like this is broken in the current API version.

Even worse, in the background the app keeps handling the back button events as if there is no child browser at all. So when the user finally clicks the close button after trying it with the back button several times, he'll end up in a whole different part of the app.

Anyone else who could reproduce this?

I'm using `Trigger.io` with the current platform version to build my android app.

Comment: This might be a bug introduced by http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/modules/event.html#backpressed-addlistener in v1.4.19 - I'll look into it...

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but I think the bug already existed in v1.4.18.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be fixed in v1.4.20 (release notes: http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/release-notes.html#v1-4-20).

Let us know if you still have any problems.